# Copying all file contents into a char array with fread

Tags: c, fopen

I'm trying to copy the contents of a file, specifically a PDF file into a character array so that I can send it over the network.

I'm using the fopen with fread for this.

```
//Get the file path
getFilePath();
//Open the file
fopen_s(&fp, filePath, "r");
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
size = ftell(fp);
rewind(fp);
//allocate memory
buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);

int charsTransferred = fread(buffer, 1, size, fp);

fclose(fp);
free(buffer);
```

I have charsTransferred to see how many characters were transferred over by fread. Using size I can tell how many characters should have been moved over, but obviously I'm not getting that many back. Does anyone know what the issue here could be?

Comment: You shouldn't try to read the entire file into memory. Files could be very huge - Order of GBs and the program would work incredibly slow because of such huge allocations. What you can do instead is read in chunks. Chunks of say 4 KBs. Anyway, you have to send it over network. There too you can send in chunks

Comment: Try with `fopen_s(&fp, filePath, "rb");`.

Comment: Also check if `buffer` actually has memory allocated or it is NULL. malloc might have failed because of huge size and you might be ignoring that.

Comment: Can you also print `size` and `charsTransferred` ? It will give some idea about what is actually happening.

Comment: Your code looks correct (apart from the lack of error checking and not using "rb" with `fopen`.). What values do you get in `charsTransferred ` and in `size `? Anyway, check if `fopen_s` actually succeeds, the file may not exist or your default directory is not the one you think.

Comment: @MichaelWalz  I get 341172 in size and 704 in charsTransferred, I am trying to open a pdf file.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I've got the contents of those variables here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a problem in the part of your code you didn't show.

This works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
  FILE *fp;

  if (fopen_s(&fp, "somepdfile.pdf", "rb"))
  {
    printf("Failed to open file\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
  int size = ftell(fp);
  rewind(fp);

  char *buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
  if (!buffer)
  {
    printf("Failed to malloc\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  int charsTransferred = fread(buffer, 1, size, fp);
  printf("charsTransferred = %d, size = %d\n", charsTransferred, size);

  fclose(fp);
  free(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Tried it, and while it does move over the correct amount, if fills it with garbage: [picture of contents](http://imgur.com/a/3qwLU)

Comment: How did you check it's garbage? If you look at the raw bytes of a PDF file it _does_ look like garbage. Try it with a text file instead of a PDF file.

Comment: Tried the text file, the text file only has one 's' and i still got the same content as i did above. the specific Y character

Comment: Maybe you IDE is broken and the values showed are wrong. Try with a text file and print the first 20 characters in buffer right after `fread`.

Comment: ... wait, __when exactly__ did you look at `buffer`? Once the program has stopped?

Comment: I added a breakpoint and hovered over the variable in the Visual Studio

Comment: OK, looks like something in VS is broken. Try printing the first 20 or so characters right after fread, I'm sure it will work. Or. where exactly did you put the breakpoint?

Comment: My crystall ball tells me you put the breakpoint __after__ `free`, then it's normal you get garbage. The memory content of `buffer` is undefined after the call to `free`.

Comment: You got me, I DID put the breakpoint after the free. It is indeed sending everything over. One last thing, the buffer array is always ended with 4 garbage characters, right after the text.

Comment: @ashmont I'd ask another question for this.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to open in binary mode if a PDF, which I believe is a binary format. Then the seek end / ftell method tends to fail for very large files, as well as for text files (which have suppressed characters physically on the disk). There isn't a pure ANSI C way of statting a file, but the function stat() is widely avialable, and gives you file size.

Comment: I've used this to get the size but still get the same error occuring